# Problems with Twilio Plugins for Dynamics 365 integration

Tags: plugins, flexbox, twilio, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm using the Twilio Plugin tutorial https://www.twilio.com/blog/integrate-flex-microsoft-dynamics-365 to create a plugin to handle screenpop and click to dial.
Even when I use their sample code from github the loadjs statements throw exceptions.

Has anyone got this working?

We're developing on Windows 10 using vscode, debugging locally using chrome.

Comment: What are the exceptions that are thrown? Are the load issues because you need to [register the URLs you are embedding Flex in](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/setup/secure-iframe)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a robust and fully supported Dynamics integration with Twilio Flex, please see the Ciptex Race Microsoft Dynamics solution for Twilio Flex extension. more info here https://showcase.twilio.com/partner-listing/a8E8Z000000HOxNUAW